# How to replace a single quotation mark (') in dict key in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, replace

There is a dict

```
example = {'view_id_ga_standard_111': {'view_id': '111',
  'request_type': 'ga_standard',
  'start_date': '2019-07-01',
  'end_date': '2019-09-01',
  'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:users'}],
  'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:year'}],
  'dimensionFilterClauses': ['{"filters": [{"dimensionName": "ga:pagePath", "operator": "EXACT","expressions": ["/de/de/1111/"]}}']}}
```

I need to get rid of a single qm here: `['{"filters": [{"dimensionName": "ga:pagePath", "operator": "EXACT","expressions": ["/de/de/111/"]}}']`

It should be like this: `[{"filters": [{"dimensionName": "ga:pagePath", "operator": "EXACT","expressions": ["/de/de/111/"]}}]`

I have tried a simple way:

```
example['view_id_ga_standard_111']['dimensionFilterClauses'][0].replace("'", "")
```

and like this

```
example['view_id_ga_standard_111']['dimensionFilterClauses'][0].replace('\'', '')
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: You want to turn a string into a dict. That won't happen by removing the quote that delimits the string, that happens by *parsing* the string using an appropriate parser. This looks like it might be a JSON string parsable by a JSON parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"]" is missing in last word ["/de/de/111/"]}}'],your example data. It should be like this: ["/de/de/111/"]}]}']

#### method:1 (missing "]")

```
tmp_str1 = example['view_id_ga_standard_111']['dimensionFilterClauses'][0]
# tmp_str1 = '{"filters": [{"dimensionName": "ga:pagePath", "operator": "EXACT","expressions": ["/de/de/111/"]}}'
tmp_str2 = tmp_str1.replace(']}}', ']}]}')
#tmp_str2 = '{"filters": [{"dimensionName": "ga:pagePath", "operator": "EXACT","expressions": ["/de/de/111/"]}]}'
result = eval(tmp_str2)
print(result)
example['view_id_ga_standard_111']['dimensionFilterClauses'][0] = result
```

#### method:2 (NOT missing "]". if this is typing error)

```
tmp_str = example['view_id_ga_standard_111']['dimensionFilterClauses'][0]
# tmp_str = '{"filters": [{"dimensionName": "ga:pagePath", "operator": "EXACT","expressions": ["/de/de/111/"]}]}'
result = eval(tmp_str)
print(result)
example['view_id_ga_standard_111']['dimensionFilterClauses'][0] = result
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a string, where you would actually like a dictionary object.

Try this:

```
import json

example['view_id_ga_standard_111']['dimensionFilterClauses'][0] = json.loads(example['view_id_ga_standard_111']['dimensionFilterClauses'][0])
```

Comment: Hello, I have tried but it returns an error JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 99 (char 98)

Comment: It is missing a `]` so it is not valid json. Changing to `..../de/1111/"]}]}']}}` will make it work.